# How to find maximum running pod over last 24 hour using prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, amazon-eks, promql

I have deploy my kubernetes cluster in AWS EKS. I have setup prometheus and grafana to monitor the EKS cluster. How to find Max no of running pods throughout the day ??

Answer (score 0):

This one will return the name of the pods that have been run in the last 24 hours. Note there can be exited pods also, that doesn't exist now.

```
sum by (pod) (min_over_time(kube_pod_start_time[24h]))
```

The following query should return the number of pods that existed in the last 24 hours:

```
count(last_over_time(kube_pod_created[24h]))
```

The last_over_time(kube_pod_created[24h]) returns time series for pods that existed in the last 24 hours

For more information follow [pod metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/pod-metrics.md).

Comment: this query retun pods that are created in last 24 hour. I am interested in the maximum pod running count  during last 24 hour. pod  start time can be anything.

Comment: @AkshayGopani Try this query which evaluates the pods running in the last 24hr `count by (namespace,pod) (kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Running",duration="24h"})`

Answer (score 0):

The following query should return the maximum number of running pods during the last 24 hours:

```
max_over_time(
  count(kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Running"})[24h:1m]
)
```

It uses [subquery feature](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/), [max_over_time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#max_over_time) function and [count()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count) function.

Comment: i am getting empty query result. @valyala

Comment: @AkshayGopani Confirm that the metric name and label selector are correct: Double-check the metric name and label selector in your PromQL query. The kube_pod_status_phase metric should have the phase label set to "Running". Ensure that the label and value are spelled correctly.